# Neo4j SDN 4 Cypher query based on GraphId and entity type

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have implemented a base class for all entities in my application that can have a subscribers:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class Subscribable extends BaseEntity {

    private final static String SUBSCRIBED_TO = "SUBSCRIBED_TO";

    @Relationship(type = SUBSCRIBED_TO, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<User> subscribers = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<User> getSubscribers() {
        return subscribers;
    }

    public void setSubscribers(Set<User> subscribers) {
        this.subscribers = subscribers;
    }

    public boolean addSubscriber(User subscriber) {
        return subscribers.add(subscriber);
    }

}
```

Also I have a few concrete types that extend `Subscribable` class, for example `Product`, `Tag`, `User` etc

Right now in order to get all `User` subscribed to a particular `Subscribable` I use a following method with a Cypher query:

```
@Query("MATCH (sub:Subscribable)<-[:SUBSCRIBED_TO]-(u:User) WHERE id(sub) = {subscribableId} RETURN u")
Set<User> findAllUsersBySubscribableId(@Param("subscribableId") Long subscribableId);
```

The issue is that AFAIK different objects of different types can potentially have the same Id so looks like the approach to get all `User` based only on `subscribableId`(GraphId) can not be consistent and potentially  can lead to a different results.

The idea is to supply additional parameter to `findAllUsersBySubscribableId` method, for example `String type` in order to specify what exact type I expect under provided `subscribableId`.. for example "Product"

Please help to extend the following Cypher query in order to support entity type:

```
MATCH (sub:Subscribable)<-[:SUBSCRIBED_TO]-(u:User) WHERE id(sub) = {subscribableId} RETURN u
```